# How do i use twilio to enter information with touch tone

Tags: twilio

How can I use twilio to enter numerical data to an automated system and specifically record(transcribe?) the result?

I am not a programmer yet but I am trying to learn. Is there an application I might customize to meet my needs?
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: Hey, are you looking to create something that can make calls and enter information for you? If that's the case, check out using [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) and the [`Digits` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play#attributes-digits). If you're looking for an application that can receive input, take a look at [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather). What sort of programming experience do you have?

Comment: I would like to share I dont really have experience programming. I have some manuals for java and Python and I think I have the ability to try something simple. To enter 18 digit consecutive numbers followed by the mod10 check result and transcribe the automatic response